# How to do databind to devexpress gridview using C# code on winforms app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I am new to winforms. I am trying to call stored procedure and display into devexpress gridview control

Here is my code what I tried

```
//Header file
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;



public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //string cs = Properties.Settings.TestDatabaseConnectionString;
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDatabaseConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = connectionString;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = "ReportStudentDetails";
            cmd.Connection = con;

            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            sda.Fill(ds);

            gridControl1.DataSource = ds;
            gridControl1.DataBind(); // showing error
            con.Close();

        }

    }
```

**Error:**

> GridControl1 Doesn't contain a definition of data bind

Comment: Remove the `gridControl1.DataBind();` line. `gridControl1.DataSource = ds;` is sufficient.

Comment: In addition, ASP.NET and WinForms are incompatible technologies. How are you using them together?

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten As you mentiones I removed. Now there is no error. But at the same time It doesn't show any records

Comment: Set the grid data source to the required table of your DataSet. For example: `gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`

Comment: @Gosha_Fighten Bro you are correct, Can you please explain more detail on your answer, it will be more helpful to others also

Comment: Sure, I've added my answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataBind` method is specific to ASP.NET controls. In WinForms, everything is tracked by setting a control property. So, there is no need to use the `DataBind` method.

Then, DataSet is not bindable object. It contains a collection of such object. They are DataTables. So, it's necessary to set the DataSource property to one of the DataSet tables. For example, `gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];`. Or, if you have named tables, `gridControl1.DataSource = ds.Tables['myTableName'];`. Alternatively, you can use the GridControl [DataMember](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl.DataMember.property) property to specify the table name.

```
gridControl1.DataSource = ds;
gridControl1.DataMember = "myTableName";
```